# Woocommerce Dashboard: Unable to access Products from backend

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am facing an strange issue. I am working on an woocommerce store, it was working fine suddenly I am unable to access **Products** list from backend i.e. **Products > All Products**. Infact I can access **Add New** product and also all the things are working fine. I haven't installed any new plugin. I have tried creating a new **.htaccess** file but that didn't work, i'm stuck.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you please make the issue more clear? Or you can enable debug option from wp-config.php by file and check if its showing some error. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Marshal, can you please define how to enable debug option and where does it show the error. I am new to it...

Comment: Hi, Please replace define( 'WP_DEBUG', false ); with define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

Comment: Hey logout/Login. Then Go to settings > Permalinks and save. Did that solve it?

Comment: hey, i deactivated some of the plugins and got issue solved. thanks for your help